# Update user Tags direct from civiMail link

Tags: civimail, contacts, tags

We'd like to let existing civiCRM Contacts tell us what they are interested in by following a link in a civiMail email, which takes them to a form with a few checkboxes. They check a few boxes, then press enter, which automatically updates their profile without making them login.

We are thinking we may need to use a [checksum Token](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/) that links to a Petition or a Survey.

I thought I'd ask what the best practice is on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create a custom field with check boxes for the subjects you wish to gather info on. Then create a profile that includes the custom field and any other info you might want to have them provide. Then use a link with a checksum token to this profile for editing in the email.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One issue with this is that the custom field check boxes will be used in the way we usually use tags, so this duplicates conceptual functions in the system – would be simpler just to use the main civi Tags system (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/) somehow.